# Centralized logging for nodejs system

Tags: node.js, logs

I am writing an algorithm trading system in nodejs, except for the third-party library such as Winston to store the log locally, is there any tool or platform that provides centralized logging service that can recommend for

1. large logging size and high efficiency (more than 1000 json per minute need to be logged)
2. quick filter and categorize (log for trading history, wallet amount, price feed data, different categories)
3. user friendly with clear document and CS support (non open source)/ active maintenance (open source)